# Google map in web based application works even without internet connection?

Tags: google-maps

is it possible to have an application (web-based) with google map api that works even without internet connection?

Say have to cache or store the map somewhere, so that when there is no internet connection the application still works.

Comment: I believe caching the tiles yourself will probably breach their EULA.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. Google Maps is a web service, which you can place into your application via an API key.

Therefore, you'll need to have an internet connection to actually make a call to the Google Maps web service to validate your API key and load it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean a web application running internally within an intranet to access Google maps. This [link](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/b002e926ad761e34) might give you some clues evn though there seems to have an Android version of this feature. A google search on "offline google maps" returned quite a few Android links